# Expand an image or background when div is hovered

Tags: jquery, css, mouseover

I need a div background image to expand when the div is hovered. What would the best way to do this be?

It needs to be a smooth animation. Ideally I would like to use JQuery but I am very new to coding so is there a ready made code I could use?

I Have just created this code and IT WORKS A TREAT! I hope it helps

```
<img class="wooll" src="/images1" style="position: absolute; margin: 0 0 0 20px;" />

<img  style="" src="/images2" class="grow"/>


$(".wooll, .grow").hover(function() {
   $('.grow').animate({
        'height': $(this).height() * 1.4,
        'width': $(this).width() * 1.4
    });
}, function() {
    $('wool, .grow').animate({
        'height': $(this).height() / 1,
        'width': $(this).width() / 1
    });
});​
```

Comment: @VladimirStarkov http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/1/ but it is not expanding evenly eitherside and the expansion is not activated when the other image is hovered. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example of the syntax and a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7UTHM/).

```
$("#mydiv").mouseover(function(){
    $("#mydiv").animate({width: '200', height: '200'},200);
});
```

I would highly recommend reading about the [animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in the JQuery API and exploring the features of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Very simple way of doing it!**
You can use CSS3 for the smooth transition, just apply this to the background in css:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

Then for the hover

```
div:hover .background {
background-size: cover /* or you can use width/height */
}
```

Working example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/3/

Comment: what would make the actual background image expand like this?

Comment: i updated the fiddle to make it work just as you needed it to - http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/5/
In CSS, on the div: hover you're giving it larger sizes which when hovered, it will increase the size from the set dimensions on the normal div to the new hover dimensions. The transition CSS3 effect animates the process.

Comment: is there a way to have the trigger div inside the expanding div but not to expand itself?

Comment: i think just by putting the div inside should work, but give the trigger div a fixed width and height

Comment: please see my update, I have altered it and it is not going very well http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/6/

Comment: You had forgot to set the new names for your divs in the css:
http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/9/

Comment: thanks for this, I have managed to do it and my code can be seen in the Question as I edited it. Thanks for your help but I wrapped both images in a div and made that div trigger the animate. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/8/ . I am banned from asking questions in S/O now. I am well upset!

Answer (score 0):

With **CSS3**, you can add an effect when changing from one style to another, without using Flash animations or JavaScripts and with use of only **pure css**.

see the demo :- [**DEMO1**](http://tinkerbin.com/9xjOfqc4)

see the demo :- [**DEMO2**](http://tinkerbin.com/9d1dkdua)

I hope this will help you

**HTML**

```
<div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
div:hover {
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:yellow;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: This is great but I have tried and the actual background image itself needs to expand. What would make this happen? @Shailender